# Why (and how?) is get_header() erasing all my stuff?

Tags: page-template, variables

I have a `page.php` in which I am defining a custom sub-menu to pass to `header.php`.

I've tried using a constant (clumsy, I know):

```
define("CUSTOM_MENU", "<ul><li>Test</li></ul>");
```

right after this, the code is including the header:

```
get_header();
```

In the header.php file, where the sub menu is, I am outputting either the custom sub-menu (if set), or a `wp_nav_menu`:

```
if (defined("CUSTOM_MENU"))
  echo constant("CUSTOM_MENU");
else
  wp_nav_menu(array(some stuff));
```

bizarrely though, the `CUSTOM_MENU` constant becomes empty the moment `get_header()` gets called - and stays empty for the rest of `page.php`:

```
 define("CUSTOM_MENU", "<ul><li>Test</li></ul>");

 echo constant("CUSTOM_MENU"); // The HTML code above

 get_header();

 echo constant("CUSTOM_MENU"); // Null!
```

This happens for *any* method of storing the custom menu data that I use. I have tried:

- Different constant names
- Namespaced constants
- Global variables
- A function with a static variable

I can't get my head around why this would happen! If `get_header()` somehow was including header.php using the http wrapper, then the value wouldn't be unset once we exit `get_header()` again.

What is going on here? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: There's better ways to do this. For example, inside header.php you could check for is_page(), to output a different header in page.php.

Comment: @Jacob I'm defining page-specific sub menus. (They have custom filtering functionality that I can't achieve with a normal `wp_nav_menu()`). The `page-xxx.php` file for each page would be the ideal location for defining each menu... although I'm open to whatever method works!

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely an issue of load order. The `get_header()` function does included your `header.php` file, so I'm not sure what's happening inside that template. One way to figure out is to include it using `include()` and check if the behavior is the same.

I would suggest you hook into the `wp_head` or `init` and define your constant there.

```
add_action('init', 'define_my_constant' );
function define_my_constant() {
    if ( ! defined( 'CUSTOM_MENU' ) && is_page() ) {
        define('CUSTOM_MENU', '<ul><li>Test</li></ul>');
    }
}
```

`init` is one of the earliest hooks that runs on WordPress, so your constant should be accessible in any theme or plugins at that point.

Comment: Didn't think of doing a simple `include()`, will try that out! I could hook into `init`, but I'm defining page-specific sub-menus. Each page's `page-xxx.php` file would be the ideal and most straightforward location for that... but if all else fails, I'll revert to that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Although you are right about the `page-xxx.php`, you can still do that by using `if( is_page('xxx') )` in conjunction with a `switch`. This way your constant is available everywhere, even in plugins!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to short-circut the `wp_nav_menu()` with this filter, for a given `theme_location`, on given pages:

```
/**
 * Filters whether to short-circuit the wp_nav_menu() output.
 *
 * Returning a non-null value to the filter will short-circuit
 * wp_nav_menu(), echoing that value if $args->echo is true,
 * returning that value otherwise.
 *
 * @since 3.9.0
 *
 * @see wp_nav_menu()
 *
 * @param string|null $output Nav menu output to short-circuit with. Default null.
 * @param stdClass    $args   An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 */
$nav_menu = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', null, $args );
```

**Example:**

Here we override the navgational menu output, at the `primary` theme location, for the `test` page:

```
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', function( $nav_menu, $args )
{
    if ( 'primary' !== $args->theme_location )
        return $nav_menu;

     if( is_page( 'test' ) )
        $nav_menu = '<ul><li>Test</li></ul>';

    return $nav_menu;
}, 10, 2 );
```